# Error : : (-2147417848, 'The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.', None, None) Python2.7 Win-32com

Tags: python, excel, win32com, windows-server, office-automation

I'm trying to run a python2.7 code to open a Excel file and pass args to Macro then to fetch the output and save it in csv file. This runs successfully in local windows 10 machine. I shifted the code from local machine to a windows server recently. when I try to compile it there it throws error.

Code :

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch
# send message to excel macro, save data as csv for each Ts
loc = path
#print loc
# open excel, run macro called "external_Run" with argList
#xls=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xls = EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = xls.Workbooks.Open(Filename=loc)
try:    
    xls.Application.Run("external_Run",argList)
except Exception as e:    
    print "--------------- ERROR ------------------"    
    print(e)    
    print "=> No data was found, please check your input file"    
    raise        
#xls.Visible = True
#wb.close()
# disable asking dialog when close excel
xls.DisplayAlerts = False
# export first sheet (macro output) to csv
w=wb.Worksheets(1)
w.SaveAs(path +'#'+'.csv')
#w.close()
xls.Application.Quit()
del xls
```

In windows local machine code runs successfully with `xls=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")` this option. But in server this option **throws Attribute Error**. So I changed `Client.Dispatch` to `EnsureDispatch`. After changed to `EnsureDispatch`  the code always appears to work on couple of files for the first time that it is run, and it throws errors or the unexpected behaviors during subsequent calls to the same code. Like if the code has to run for 10 times it runs for 3 or 4 times successfully and creates output.But on 5th time it throws error.

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\subrta1\Documents\01_OMT_Calculator\callLedCalculator.py", line 27, in messageToCal
    w=wb.Worksheets(1)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\MHEGA\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 513, in __getattr__
    if d is not None: return getattr(d, attr)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\MHEGA\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 474, in __getattr__
    return self._ApplyTypes_(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\MHEGA\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 467, in _ApplyTypes_
    self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
com_error: (-2147417848, 'The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.', None, None)
```

Kindly Help me finding out why this is happening and how to work around it?

Comment: Hard to say, but looks like a timing issue if you are running this script back-to-back for different files. The error is telling you that the Excel application has gone away: likely because your script calls `Quit()`. Maybe try adding a pause between each running of the script?

Answer (score 0):

> This runs successfully in local windows 10 machine. I shifted the code from local machine to a windows server recently.

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

As a possible workaround you may consider using the Open XML SDK if you deal with open XML documents only, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information. Also consider third-party components designed for the server-side execution.